# population pyramid for both current situation and prediction in ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with two populations, `census` and  `prediction`.

```
u.s_male<- tibble(age= 10:21, census= c(41:52),
prediction=c(42:53),country= "U.S.A",gender=1)
u.k_male<- tibble(age= 10:21, census= c(50:61),
prediction=c(51:62),country= "U.K",gender= 1)

u.s_female<- tibble(age= 10:21, census= c(40:51),
prediction=c(41:52),country= "U.S.A",gender=2)
u.k_female<- tibble(age= 10:21, census= c(49:60),
prediction=c(50:61),country= "U.K",gender= 2)

df<- rbind(u.s_female,u.s_male,u.k_female,u.k_male)
```

by the code below, I got population pyramid only for one population ,`census`,  but I would like to indicate both the census and the prediction.

```
ggplot(data =  df, aes(
  x = age,
  y = ifelse(gender == 1, -census, census),
  fill = gender
)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Male", "Female"))+
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~country)+
  xlab("age") + ylab("population")
```

my desired output would be something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try plotting the 'census' and 'predict' variables through fill and colour without fill respectevely.

```
ggplot(data =  df, aes(
x = age,
y = ifelse(gender == 1, -census, census),
fill = as.factor(gender))) +
geom_col() +
geom_col(aes(y = ifelse(gender == 1, -prediction, prediction), colour = as.factor(gender)), alpha = 0) +
scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Male", "Female")) +
scale_colour_manual(values = c( "red", "blue"), labels = c("Male", "Female")) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-40, 40, 40), 
                   labels = as.character(c(40, 0, 40))) +
labs(colour = "Prediction", fill = "Census") +
coord_flip() +
facet_wrap(~country)+
xlab("age") + ylab("population")
```

[image]